# Shelving and Peak filters name

Tags: filters

Why are Peak filters called "Peak" and why are Shelving filters called "Shelving". I am not a native English speaker. So excuse me if it is so dumb question.

[image: Shelving filter]

[image: Peak filter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the craziest, though important question on DSP SE ;) Answer is, because they:

- look like ***peak***:

[image]

- and tend to have a ***shelf*** either in the beginning or the end of frequency range:

[image]

Comment: I never thought that the answer would be that simple :)

Comment: up arrow from me.

Answer (score 1):

Fear of noises... Shelving filters are named to remind audio technologists that most people fear the ocean, i.e., the following picture. 
[image: Diagram of Continental Shelf]

The little it is worth; but note that a summer day spent on the continental shelf is scarier than just about every sound producible by humans. I myself would not have guessed this to be the reason - fear and prayers against devils and demons make up a great deal of the superfluity that is coined into terminology.

Comment: up arrow from me. $$ :-) $$